# Compactness and Totally Bounded Sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

Suppose that $(K,d)$ is a compact metric space, and $\varepsilon>0$. Prove that there is a finite subset $S⊆K$ so that for every $y∈K$ there is $x∈S$ with $d(x,y)<\varepsilon$, and moreover so that for any distinct $x,w∈S$ we have $d(x,w)>\varepsilon/2$.

I dont know how to approach $d(x,w)>\varepsilon/2$.

So far I have, $d(x_i,w) - d(w,y) \le d(x,w)\ge d(x_i,w) - \varepsilon/2 \le d(x,w)$ but it seems wrong.

Comment: I think you forgot to say that $S$ should be finite. How would you use the definition of compactness in terms of open covers to find a possible $S$?

Comment: sorry, will do next time!

Comment: @EthanBolker: I am sure the problem was meant to say explicitly that $S$ should be finite, However, the second condition on $S$ implies that $S$ must be finite (since an infinite $S$ would have a point of accumulation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have proved that there is a finite set $S$ such that every point of $X$ is within distance $\varepsilon$ of some point of $S$ (cover every point with $\varepsilon$-balls, extract a finite subcover).

For the second part, try induction on the size of the covering. A valid inductive hypothesis might be, "suppose that for any compact metric space admitting a covering of $\leq n$ points, such a configuration with pairs of points distance $\varepsilon/2$ apart exists". The base case of $n = 1$ (or $n=0$ with the empty space) is trivial. If you have a minimal covering with $n+1$ points (i.e. if you remove some $\varepsilon$-ball, you no longer have a cover), then apply the inductive hypothesis to the closure of the subspace $Y$ covered by $n$ points, and judiciously choose the spot for the $(n+1)$-st (e.g. on the boundary of $Y$).

Comment: Now that I think of it, you may need to add multiple points to the boundary of $Y$ to cover $X$, but a similar inductive argument is enough to show that you can choose these to have distance at least $\varepsilon/2$ of one another.